# Veracode missing supporting files

Tags: jenkins, veracode

I'm using Upload & scan method for my Java Maven project, but everytime after waiting between 10 to 20min, I receive an empty Veracode report

```
        stage('Upload & Scan') {
          steps {
            veracode applicationName: '****',
            criticality: 'VeryHigh',            
            createSandbox: true,
            sandboxName: '*****',
            scanName: "22/11/2021-9h23",
            waitForScan: true,
            timeout: 120,
            uploadIncludesPattern: "****.zip",
            vid: '********',
            vkey: '******',
            debug: true
          }
        }
```

FYI: before this stage i have 3 other stages: Build, Deploy in artifactory and zip (for zipping JARs

Answer (score 1):

Have you follow the [compilation instructions](https://docs.veracode.com/r/compilation_java) for Java?

Using the standard Java compiler, run the javac command with the -g option to obtain debug symbols, for example:

```
javac -g test1.java
```

Eclipse IDE Settings -
If you develop the project with Eclipse:

1. Go to Project > Properties.
2. Select the Java compiler properties.
3. Under Classfile Generation, select these options:

   - Add variable attributes to generated class files
   - Add line number attributes to generated class files
   - Add source file name to generated class files

Maven Settings -
If you build the project using Maven, include a directive to use the Maven compiler plugin in pom.xml, for example:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin> 
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
      <configuration>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

After making this change, use mvn compile or mvn package to build and package the project. The project now includes debug symbols with the application.

Gradle Settings -
If you use Gradle to build the project, after applying the Java plugin, configure the build task to add line numbers and local variables in the build.gradle file. For example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
compileJava.options.debug = true
compileJava.options.debugOptions.debugLevel = "source,lines,vars"
```

Ant Settings -
If you build the project using Ant, you must enable the debug property in the javac tasks, for example:

```
<javac debug="on"> ... set of classes
     </javac>
```